# Import XML (tree structure) into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, import, xml-parsing

I have an XML file with tree structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doct timestamp="14.11.2015 05:15:06" title="test.ru directories structure export with articles">
    <page>
        <page_id>1</page_id>
        <name>Catalog</name>
        <uri>catalog</uri>
        <page parent_page_id="1">
            <page_id>1104128</page_id>
            <name>Vehicles</name>
            <uri>vehicles</uri>
                <page parent_page_id="1104128">
                    <page_id>1105688</page_id>
                    <name>Cars</name>
                    <uri>cars</uri>
                        <product>
                            <page>1105688</page>
                            <product>49876</product>
                        </product>
                        <product>
                            <page>1105688</page>
                            <product>3525</product>
                        </product>
                        <product>
                            <page>1105688</page>
                            <product>50131</product>
                        </product>
                </page>
                <page parent_page_id="1104128">
                    <page_id>1105856</page_id>
                    <name>Planes</name>
                    <uri>planes</uri>
                        <product>
                            <page>1105856</page>
                            <product>31387</product>
                        </product>
                        <product>
                            <page>1105856</page>
                            <product>31567</product>
                        </product>
                </page>
        </page>
        <page parent_page_id="1">
            <page_id>1125468</page_id>
            <name>Сlothes</name>
            <uri>clothes</uri>
                <page parent_page_id="1125468">
                    <page_id>1378596</page_id>
                    <name>T-shirts</name>
                    <uri>t-shirts</uri>
                        <product>
                            <page>1378596</page>
                            <product>45648</product>
                        </product>
                        <product>
                            <page>1378596</page>
                            <product>5777</product>
                        </product>
                </page>
        </page>
    </page>
</doct>
```

I created 3 tables in database:

table "categories" with columns:
page_id | name | uri

table "subcategories" with columns:
parent_page_id | page_id | name | uri

table "products" with columns:
page | product

I tried to use:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "tree.xml"
INTO TABLE products
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>';
```

This command import all products successfully, but duplicate each product:

```
page    | product
-----------------
1106965 | 58814
-----------------
1106965 | 58814
-----------------
1106965 | 58955
-----------------
1106965 | 58955
-----------------
1106965 | 59079
-----------------
1106965 | 59079
```

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I import categories and subcategories?
2. What I did wrong with products? (why products was duplicated?)

Thanks in advance!